# Find similar to X509EncodedKeySpec in C#

Tags: java, c#, cryptography

All I need is just to get this lines of code in C#, Actually I can't find `X509EncodedKeySpec` in C#:

```
byte[] keyByte = Base64.decode(publicKey);

// generate public key
X509EncodedKeySpec s = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyByte);
KeyFactory factory = null;

try 
{
    factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
} 
catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Key pubKey = null;
try 
{
    pubKey = factory.generatePublic(s);
} 
catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is anything about it. but still, have a look at the [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.dotnet.security/2FiVU04vcQM)

Answer (score 1):

#### As of .NET Core 3.0 **`ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo`** is available

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importsubjectpublickeyinfo?view=netcore-3.0

You should be able to use it as follows:

```
using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
{
     rsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(publicKey, out _);
     //do your stuff 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`X509EncodedKeySpec` is Java's version of X.509 `SubjectPublicKeyInfo`.  .NET doesn't have any API built-in for reading SubjectPublicKeyInfo.  For best results, you want to have a full certificate, then use `cert.GetRSAPublicKey()`.

If you can get the transmitted as the RSA Modulus and RSA (Public) Exponent values then you could build the RSAParameters object to load into a key.

```
using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
{
    rsa.ImportParameters(new RSAParameters { Modulus = modulus, Exponent = exponent });
    // do public key things
}
```

Comment: Just as a note, there is a built in way now - https://stackoverflow.com/a/66393122/2892378